# Understanding when to use Object as return type

Tags: java

Please consider the following piece of code. I am trying to understand the need of `Object` return type. May be I haven't understood properly when should we actually be using return type as Object in a method, I was going
through the following code and as you can see, the `AdNewCpp` method is called inside `doGet` method and the return type of `AdNewCpp` method has been defined as `Object`. I am wondering if there can be something
else that can be used in place of `Object` as the return type?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // Use ResourceBundle to keep localized string in "LocalStrings_xx.properties"

        // Write the response message, in an HTML page
        try {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html");  // HTML 5
            out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");

            out.println(AddNewCpp("cpp test - new"));

            out.println("<head><title>Test API</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h3>TestAPI</h3>");

            // Tabulate the request information 
            out.println("</body></html>");
        }   
        finally {
            out.close();  // Always close the output writer
        }
    }

    public static Object AddNewCpp(String cppDesc) throws IOException {
        String accessKey = "DNN7ACCESSKEYEXAMPLE";
        String secretKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
        String uRLCppList = "http://something.com/abc";
        String method = "POST";
        java.util.Date currentTime = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        // Give it to me in GMT time.
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String dateTimeString = sdf.format(currentTime);

        String signature = generateSignature(method, secretKey, dateTimeString);
        String authorization = accessKey + ":" + signature;
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("cppListDesc", cppDesc);

        String[] result = sendHttpRequest(uRLCppList, "POST", params, dateTimeString, authorization);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: In your case why wouldn't you return a `String` (i.e. `result.toString()`) ?

Comment: Yes you can return `String[]` instead of **Object**

Comment: Just wondering, it is a bad practice to use `Object` as a return type?

Comment: Yes, it is if you have more specific return type to Use , but if Object is the only Option which is a very rare case then you might need it , but after Generics this rare has became rarer!

Comment: I would never do that. If there exists a condition where you could return instances of *different types*, only then you could try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are returning a `String` array in any case, at least here, so you could replace the `Object` with `String[]`, which wouldn't change much, especially as the `out.println` will not present a very readable result anyway.

You are using an Object as a return code if you know of no more specific types to use. But of course, this means, that the method using that return code has to be prepared to cope with anything. In your example, this is done by implicitly calling `toString()` (by `out.println`), which every Object has. In many other cases, you would have to do many `instanceof` checks to see, what the Object actually is.

Personally, I would try to avoid it, as it makes code inherently surprising: Just be reading the method signature you do not know what to expect as result, you would have to read the method itself or worse, the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can return  `String []` as you are actually returning the String Array from your **AddNewCpp method**

```
public static String[] addNewCpp(String cppDesc) throws IOException{
                               /\    
                               ||
            //Method Name Should be in camelCase(good Practice)
 String[] result = sendHttpRequest(uRLCppList, "POST", params, dateTimeString, authorization);
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I don't see why AddNewCpp would not return a String[]. The direct use of the Object class is also less need since Java has generics.